# AWS cloudformation stack state

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I would like to have a function in python(boto3) that checks what status the stack is (CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, CREATE_FAILED, CREATE_COMPLETE) and print the status, if the status is "CREATE_COMPLETE" print the "Stack Outputs".

Hope you can help me.

Daniel W.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues have you encountered? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [Stack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Stack) object:

```
import boto3

cfnr = boto3.resource('cloudformation')

stack = cfnr.Stack('some-stack-name')

if stack.stack_status == 'CREATE_COMPLETE': 
  print(stack.outputs)
```